# Flutter web: get full screen size - not window size

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-getx

My Flutter desktop web app has complex ui that would be too tricky to make responsive. So instead I want to put it in a `FittedBox` that will simply shrink the whole app if the user makes the browser window smaller.

```
class CustomPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const CustomPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GetPlatform.isDesktop
          ? FittedBox(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: Get.width,
                height: Get.height,
                child: Center(child: child),
              ),
            )
          : Text('Sorry! This was only meant for desktop.'),
    );
  }
}
```

But `Get.width` and `WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize.width` only get the initial window size. So if the app is started in a full screen browser then this works great, but if the app is started in a small browser it doesn't work. `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` only gets the current screen size.

Is there a way of getting a desktop physical screen size?

Comment: You basically need to rebuild the UI if you want to listen to changes in dimension. You can use layout builder and then use its constraints as width and height. The layout builder will rebuild its child every time there is a change in dimensions. Just wrap your UI in Layout Builder and use constraints of layout buider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to import
`import 'dart:html';`

then `window.screen?.width` and `window.screen?.height`
will give you physycal screen size

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: Home());
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, c) {
        return Center(
          child: Text('${window.screen?.width}   ${window.screen?.height}'),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]